# Question about the nullstellensatz for projective schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Assume that $ G $ is a graded ring. Assume that $A$ is a relevant homogeneous ideal (that is, it does not contain the irrelevant ideal $ \oplus_{n > 0}G_n$). I am having trouble proving the following formula:
$$ IV(A) = \sqrt{A}$$
In this formula, $I$ takes a subset $X$ of ${\rm proj} \, G$ to the homogeneous ideal generated by homogeneous elements which vanish at every point of $X$.

It is clearly true that $ IV(A) \supseteq \sqrt{A}$ so the hard direction is $ IV(A) \subseteq \sqrt{A}$. I know we want to prove that if $ g \in G $ is homogeneous and vanishes at every point in $V(A)$ then it vanishes at every point in the affine cone of $V(A)$ and I see why this is true geometrically, but I am struggling with the commutative algebra. More explicitly, given a prime ideal $ A \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$, I want to prove that there is a relevent homogeneous prime $ A \subseteq \mathfrak{q} \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

EDIT 1: Ok I have an idea. Define 
$$ \mathfrak{p}_n = \{ \text{homogeneous elements of degree $ n $ in $ \mathfrak{p}$} \} $$
Then $ \oplus_{n \geq 0} \mathfrak{p}_n$ is a homogeneous prime ideal with $ A \subseteq \oplus_{n \geq 0} \mathfrak{p}_n \subseteq \mathfrak{p} $. The problem is that this ideal might not be relevant. Indeed, if $ G_{+} \subseteq \sqrt{A}$ then it is not relevant. The idea is that we are taking the largest homogeneous ideal which is contained in $ \mathfrak{p} $. This is is kind of like taking the line through a point in the classical situation.

Comment: What is $G$, exactly? You want to use the Nullstellensatz, so some other properties need to be around. Is it just the polynomials in $n$ variables with coefficients in an algebraically closed field, graded by degree?

Comment: @Zach: I understand how to prove the case when $G$ is a polynomial ring over a field. I feel like this should be true for any graded ring. Am I wrong?

Comment: If $G_+\subset \sqrt A\subsetneqq G$ but $G_+\nsubseteq A$, then $V(A)=\emptyset$, so $I(V(A))=G\neq \sqrt A$, is it a counterexample to your formula?

Comment: @jerrysciencemath: you are right, this is a counterexample. I will try and prove the claim assuming that the radical is relevent

Comment: @BenjaLim: A homogeneous element $ g $ vanishes at a prime $ \mathfrak{p}$ if it is contained in the prime and in your example, $A$ is not a homogeneous ideal. Thanks for getting me thinking though :D